# ASP.NET Razor Pages route parameter named page

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I want to use url parameter named page in my razor pages app:

```
http://example.com/Dataset/0?page=X
```

I tried using anchor tag helper like this:

```
<a asp-page="Dataset" asp-route-id="@(dataset.Id)" asp-route-page="@(pageNumber)">@(dataset.Title)</a>
```

But this doesnt work, it seems like asp-page and asp-route-page conflict each other, the result is:

```
http://example.com/Dataset/0
```

The above can be easily solved by typing it out in html so its not a real problem there.

The real problem: **I tried manually adding ?page=100 to the end of url, i checked the value in the OnGet method and its 0 as if the parameter is missing.**

**edit:** this method gets called when you visit the razor page in browser, the parameters of the method have the same name as parameters from the url query, they get automatically filled from the query, **except the page parameter**

```
public FileResult OnGet(int id, string subject, string predicate, string @object, int page)
    {
        // page==0 in this scope even if the query is ?page=30 etc
        // other parameters work fine
    }
```

Comment: Please share the code for the action method.

Comment: Updated with the OnGet method and described it better

Answer (score 2):

In this context "Page" is a reserved term, so you should not use it in your route or it will confuse the routing engine.

Marshall

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to send parameters in Razor syntax. 
You can use

```
@Html.ActionLink("Title","0","Dataset",new{page=100})
```

Or You can use  tag like:

```
<a href="http://example.com/Dataset/0?page=@pageNumber">@dataset.Title</a>
```

Comment: The problem is that the server somehow drops the page parameter. I can put the whole url manually like in your second example but in the OnGet method in code behind, the parameter is 0.

Comment: Have you added this method in controller?
for testing send call from browser URL to this method and check if it is receiving!
This can be issue with parameter name or data type!

Comment: You dont have to call the whole url buddy just call the page you wanna move with a parameter :) it  is tested  <a href="Dataset?Page=@dataset.pageNumber">Here You Go </a>

Answer (score 0):

You can't use **page** as route value for a razor page because that route value is used by the razor pages engine.

The path to raozor page is added to the route diccionary values as a route value with the **page** key so just change the name of the route value.